# Convert a List element to a Character String in R

Tags: r, string-parsing

I've parsed out some XML from a web page:

```
> productNodes
[[1]]
<productLabel>20-Volt Li-Ion Cordless Combo Kit (2-Tool)</productLabel> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

I would like to convert this `XMLNodeSet` List to a Character String or Atomic Vector to enable the use of the `str_extract` and `str_replace` functions.
I have tried numerous approaches and all fail to convert.

Comment: You can try `unclass`

Comment: You might want to try `xmlValue`.

Comment: Hi Thomas, this is what I got.....  test5 <- xmlValue(productNodes)
Error in UseMethod("xmlValue") : 
  no applicable method for 'xmlValue' applied to an object of class "XMLNodeSet"

Comment: You need to supply a more complete example in order for people to help you.